# Git Squash several commits into one, fast forward

Tags: git

Here's an example git log:

```
commit_hash_0 - Author: me
commit_hash_1 - Author: me
commit_hash_2 - Author: me
...
commit_hash_n-1 - Author: me
commit_hash_n - Author: some other guy
```

I am attempting to collapse all commits after (excluding) commit_hash_n into a singular commit. I found out that I could use `git rebase -i commit_hash_n` to do this. However, I am running into merge errors. I don't understand why this is happening. I simply want to keep the state of my project as it is when I made my most recent commit. So this shouldn't cause any merge issues right? What's going on?

```
The git log should be:
commit_hash_new - Author: me
commit_hash_n - Author: some other guy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to accomplish this without the possibility of conflicts, is by resetting (soft or mixed) to the nth commit, and then committing. For example:

```
git reset --soft <commit_hash_n> # using --soft leaves all changes staged
git commit -m "Do cool stuff" # this is the message for the squashed commit
```

As for *why* you had conflicts, we can't say for sure without more information, but the most common reasons for conflicts with an interactive rebase are:

1. You changed the order of some commits, or you dropped some commits, such that Git cannot cleanly cherry-pick each commit in the newly specified order.
2. Your branch is not linear, and contains merge commits after the rebase starting commit, which themselves resolved conflicts. By default merge commits are not included with a rebase, and even if you use the option `--rebase-merges` to include them, you'll need to re-resolve the conflicts that were originally resolved by those merge conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

@TTT's approach is very good (upvoted). There is another way to do it, for those curious, which avoids having to wrap around your head around a reset (which is one of my favorite tools, by the way, I do not mean you should avoid using it, it's just that it might be tricky to *get it*).

```
git checkout <commit_hash_n>
git restore --staged --worktree --source <commit_hash_0> -- .
git commit -m "Everything in a single shot"
```

At this point you can move the branch you like to the current commit.

Comment: This is very good as well (upvoted).  Is this easier to *get* than `reset` though? Hehe.

Comment: `restore`? I think it is... no need to think about _pointers_.... just what you want in the working tree/index.

Comment: Ah yes. I was (somewhat jokingly) referring to someone learning Git trying to remember the entire syntax of this command vs a soft reset. But conceptually, I agree that `restore` is simpler than `reset`.  Side note: I think the `.` path assumes your prompt is currently in the root of the repo... not sure if it's worth mentioning that.

Comment: I do not think it's necessary.